# How to add navigation to queue in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

[This](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigating-without-navigation-prop/#:%7E:text=To%20avoid%20this%2C%20you%20can%20use%20the%20isReady()%20method%20available%20on%20the%20ref%20as%20shown%20in%20the%20above%20examples.) is the docs of React Navigation. How can queue actions when navigation is not ready? (mentioned in else block)

```
import * as React from 'react';

export const navigationRef = createNavigationContainerRef()

export function navigate(name, params) {
  if (navigationRef.isReady()) {
    // Perform navigation if the react navigation is ready to handle actions
    navigationRef.navigate(name, params);
  } else {
    // You can decide what to do if react navigation is not ready
    // You can ignore this, or add these actions to a queue you can call later
  }
}
```